# Find files created within a second or two

Tags: file, shell, find

Im must to find files created within a second or two but i have no idea how. Im think best way is some find pattern. Or maybe shell script. Can someone help ?

Comment: you need to specify better what you mean by "created within a second or two", ... Of each other, of the current time, in a relatively close directory structure. If you've every tried to search from the root dir in an industrial unix file system where the search can take hours to complete, you'll realize that the files will need to be 'close to each other'. Consider editing your question to include some real examples of what you include int "a second or two" and what doesn't matter. Good luck.

Comment: Do you perhaps just want to be notified when a file is created? Linux provides the `inotify` system, BSD provides `kqueue`, and other operating systems probably provide similar alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In one dir we have ten files, five of them have some date - no matter when. Second five have dates 14:46:45, 14:46:46 and e.g. 15:33:21, 15:33:21, 15:33:22 (same day) and we have to find these.